# Prove that $f$ either vanishes at all points or at no points

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and assume $A$ is both open and connected. Let furthermore $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $A$ which converges uniformly to a holomorphic $f$ on all compact sets. Assume that $f_n$ never vanishes for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**I want to prove that $f$ either vanishes at all points or at no points.**

My idea is assuming towards a contradiction that there exists $z, z' \in \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f(z) = 0 $ and $f(z') \neq 0$. Then maybe i could somehow use Rouche's Theorem and perhaps the Maximus modulus principle to get some kind of contradiction of the boundary of some disc but I can't seem to make it work. Is it possible to do it this way? Or is there a better way (still using some Complex Analysis preferably)?

Comment: Try with [Hurwit'z theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)). There's an sketch of the proof there too.

Comment: Thanks! It seems in Hurwit'z theorem you assume the sequence is holomorphic which is not the case here though...

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was just a matter of habits! :)

Comment: A proof of this generalization of Hurwitz' Theorem can be found in:                                    A Version of Rouche's Theorem for Continuous Functions by A. Tsarpalias,
Source: The American Mathematical Monthly , Dec., 1989, Vol. 96, No. 10 (Dec., 1989), pp. 911-913