# With $\{f_n\}$ converging to $f$ holomorphic, show that $f$ is nowhere vanishing or 0 everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving an exercise that says:
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open, connected, $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions converging locally uniformly to a holomorphic function $f$, and none of $f_n$ vanishes at any point. Show that $f=0$ everywhere or nowhere.

I found a theorem I could use that says that for a holomorphic $f$ on an open, connected set, set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: f(z)=0\}$ has no limit points unless $f$ is identically $0$.

Now I'm pretty bad in complex analysis and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: For *holomorphic* functions $f_n$ that is Hurwitz's theorem, but you assume $f_n$ only to be continuous. – The same question was posted recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4251868/42969.

Comment: @MartinR didn't see that one. thanks :)

Comment: one needs to use the notion of degree for a continuous function and then for continuous functions with isolated zeroes, a lot of the stuff that works for holomorphic functions (eg a version of the argument principle, Rouche etc) works with the caveat that now (isolated) zeroes can have negative or even zero degrees so one has to be really careful; for (nonconstant) holomorphic functions the main point is that zeroes are always isolated and have positive degrees, but already even for very smooth but nonholomoprhic functions (eg harmonic ones) one can have zeroes with negative or zero degree